# VSCode nodejs debugger saying attached but its only working for one of my nodejs files

Tags: node.js, express, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I have been using the attach debugger and it was working fine until yesterday when it only seems to work on one of my nodejs files. When I attach the debugger it says its attached and I can then set a breakpoint in my loginController.js file and it will hit it when I click sign up or logout in my React front end. When I debug my React code in the same project, it works fine and hits the breakpoints where I set them.

Before this I could put a breakpoint in any of my nodejs files and it would hit them when the route handler was triggered. But now it just doesnt seem to.

[My repo](https://github.com/LukasDrinkwater/project-blog) The only file I can hit a breakpoint on is loginController.js in Backend -> Controllers.

Ive gone back to previous projects and it doesnt work on them either, I cant hit any breakpoints. Ive also gone back to previous commits where it was definitely working. Im not sure if VSCode has a bug in a recent update but I cant find anything when googling.

I also setup a blank express project and sent a postman request with the debugger attached. It doesnt trigger but postman receives the res.json message I respond with.

Ive tried multiple luanch.jsons but none work. My launch.json is in .vscode.

Answer (score 0):

### Myabe try one of these options

> ### Launching it using vscode it self

```
//...
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "request": "launch",
        "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"],
        "type": "node"
    }
]
//...
```

> ### Attaching the debugger to the node process

```bash
$ node --inspect ./bin/www
```

> and then in vscode
> Press F1 Then Type "Attach To Node Process"
> And select your process
> I would advice you for more accuracy to log the pid
> So you can be sure you are attaching to the correct process

```js
console.log(process.pid)
```

> ### Do not use nodemon
>
> maybe the nodemon is causing some issues, because of the way it's launching your app

> ### Rename /backend/bin/www
>
> maybe the name of this file is causing all these issue
> so try to rename it to /backend/bin/www.js
> or something similar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).